# JasperReports Server Pro 4.5 / JasperReports 4.5 assign roles to specific part of the report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report with different categories/departments let's say (Sales,Accounting,IT)
and 4 users:

- User 1 - (Admin) see all the departments.
- User 2 - Sales and accounting.
- User 3 - accounting only.
- User 4 - Sales Only.

The permission will be already stored in the database.

What I want something like that:

```sql
SELECT depname FROM dept 
WHERE permission=(retriev_from_jasperserver_pro_users_role)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these built-in parameters:

```
WHERE my_column in $P{LoggedInUserRoles}
AND another_column = $P{LoggedInUsername}
```